# How to signal cell entered & cell left in QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qtableview

In switching from QTableWidget to QTableView to improve the speed of my GUI, I've come to realize that there is no equivalent cellEntered signal available for QTableView. How can I achieve that?

In this GUI, I have a popup window with a QTableView that shows coordinates of markers placed on an image in a separate window.  I need to highlight the markers in the image window as the cursor is moved over the corresponding rows or cells in the QTableView coordinates table. So I need to be able to emit a signal, not just highlight the row in the coordinate table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent to [`cellEntered`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellEntered) signal is the [`entered`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#entered) signal:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 5)

    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setMouseTracking(True)

    def on_entered(index):
        print(index.row(), index.column())

    view.entered.connect(on_entered)

    view.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and example code. It works perfectly. You da man, eyllanesc!

Comment: Is there a way to tell when a cell has been "left" as well?

Answer (score 1):

Since the second part of the question has been left unanswered, I want to address the "How to catch the cell or item leave" problem.

Because there is no *cellLeft* or *ItemLeft* event, the *cellEntered* event of the surrounding cells must be used. To know when a cell has been left, we store each entered row and column and decide when a leave event occurred.

```
class LeaveEvent(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        self.table.cellEntered.connect(self.on_table_cell_entered)
        self.prev_idxs = -1, -1

    def on_table_cell_entered(self, row, column):
        if (row, column) != self.prev_idxs:
            print(f'previous cell left: {self.prev_idxs}')

        self.prev_idxs = row, column
```